# How to avoid NSpanel to be opened as different objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nspanel

I'm having a `NSCollectionView` consist of 10 `NSButtons` and also dragged a `NSpanel` from object library. If i click a button `NSpanel` should be appeared.If i clicked the next button, last generated NSpanel should closed and another NSpanel was opened. What my problem is the NSpanel was generated, if i clicked the Second Button another NSpanel appeared and the previous one was not closed.

Comment: Please show the code for your button action.

Comment: simply i NSlogged panel. i thing the NSpanel subclass object was initiated repeatedly...